# Hibernate update relation set without knowing primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In Hibernate, what is the best way I can use to update the relation set of a given entity without knowing any of the primary keys? I basically want it to check the current relation set to see if any of the related entities have all of the same field values as the one about to be saved, and if so update it otherwise create a new one.

Below is my code:

```
public void updateProcesses(ComputerEntity computerEntity, JsonNode data) {

    Set<ProcessEntity> processEntities = new HashSet<>();

    for (JsonNode process : data.get("Processes")) {
        ProcessEntity processEntity = new ProcessEntity();
        processEntity.setPid(process.get("Pid").asInt());
        processEntity.setName(process.get("Name").asText());
        processEntity.setDescription(process.get("Description").asText());
        processEntity.setWindowTitle(process.get("WindowTitle").asText());
        processEntity.setThreadCount(process.get("ThreadCount").asInt());
        processEntity.setCpu((byte) process.get("Cpu").asLong());
        processEntity.setRam(process.get("Ram").asLong());
        processEntity.setRunTime(process.get("RunTime").asLong());
        processEntity.setComputer(computerEntity);
        processEntities.add(processEntity);
    }
    computerEntity.setProcesses(processEntities);

    Session session = Fusion.instance().getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(computerEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Currently it recreates new process records in the database and does not remove or update the old ones causing duplicates.

Comment: Can u post mapping of Computer Entity and ProcessEntity (esp Cascade type ) and Entity structure here